# datepicker not getting in every row of datatables

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4, datatables, datepicker, inline-editing

I have created table using datatables. In that table I'm adding new entry with `Inline Row Add` and editing existence entry with `Inline Row Edit`. like shown In images:

[image: Inline Row Add]

[image: Inline Row Edit]

I want to add datepicker in Month/Year column for both `Inline Row Add` and `Inline Row Edit`. like mentioned in image: [image: First Row]

but Its getting only in 1st row while editing.
Its not getting while adding a new entry or while editing 2nd row and below rows. [image: Second Row]

Html Code:

```
<div class="table-responsive">
          <table class="table dataTable" id="fuelData">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>SNO</th>
                <th>OPCO</th>
                <th>Month/Year</th>
                <th>Fuel Zone</th>
                <th>Fuel Type</th>
                <th>Fuel Price/Unit</th>
                <!-- <th>OPCO</th> -->
                <th>Action</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              
              {% for f in fuelData%}
              
              <tr id="{{f.id}}">
                <td>{{ forloop.counter }}</td>
                <td>
                  <span class="editSpan fuel_opco">{{f.opco}}</span>
                  <select class="form-control editInput fuel_opco" id="add_new_opco" name="fuel_opco" style="display: none;">
                    {% for c  in opco %}
                      <option value="{{c}}">{{c}}</option>
                    {% endfor %}
                </select>
                <small class="text-danger" id="err-fuel_opco"></small>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <span class="editSpan monthyear">{{f.month_year}}</span>
                  <input class="form-control editInput monthyear" type="text" name="monthyear" id="datepicker" value="{{f.month_year}}" style="display: none;"> 
                  <small class="text-danger" id="err-monthyear"></small>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <span class="editSpan fuel_zone">{{f.fuel_zone}}</span>
                  <select class="form-control editInput fuel_zone" id="FuelZoneSelect" name="fuel_zone" style="display: none;">
                    {% for c  in FuelZone %}
                      <option value="{{c}}">{{c}}</option>  
                    {% endfor %}
                    <option value="1" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#valueModal" data-id="1">Add New Zone</option>
                  </select>
                  
                  <small class="text-danger" id="err-fuel_zone"></small>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <span class="editSpan fuel_zone">{{f.fuel_type}}</span>
                  <select class="form-control editInput fuel_zone" id="FuelZoneSelect" name="fuel_zone" style="display: none;">
                    {% for c  in FuelType %}
                      <option value="{{c}}">{{c}}</option>  
                    {% endfor %}
                   
                  </select>
                  
                  <small class="text-danger" id="err-fuel_zone"></small>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <span class="editSpan fuel_price">{{f.fuel_cost}}</span> 
                  <input class="form-control editInput fuel_price" type="number" id="editFuelPrice" name="fuel_price" value="{{f.fuel_cost}}" style="display: none;"> 
                  <small class="text-danger" id="err-fuelprice"></small>
                </td>
               
                <td> 
                  <i class='fa fa-edit editBtn' style="cursor: pointer;"></i>
                  <i class='fa fa-trash pl-3 deleteBtn' style="cursor: pointer;"></i>
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-success saveBtn" onclick="validate_Edit_Form()" style="display: none;">Save</button>
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger confirmBtn" style="display: none;">Confirm</button>
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary cancelBtn" style="display: none;">Cancel</button>
                </td>
                
              </tr>
              {% endfor %}
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
```

jquery datepicker code:

```
 $('#datepicker').datepicker({
          startView:'months',
          viewMode:'months',
          minViewMode:'months',
          format: 'mm-yyyy',
    });
```

Inline Add New row:

```
var table = $("#fuelData").DataTable();
var row = ["1",
          "<select class='form-control addInput add_fuel_opco' id='add_new_opco' name='add_fuel_opco'>"+ optionsOpcoName+"</select> <small class='text-danger' id='err-fuel_opco'></small>",
          "<input class='form-control addInput monthyear' type='text' name='monthyear' id='date_picker'>  <small class='text-danger' id='err-month_year'></small>",
          "<select class='form-control addInput add_fuel_zone' id='select_fuel_zone' name='add_fuel_zone'>"+ optionsfuelzone + "</select> <small class='text-danger' id='err-fuel_zone'></small>",
          "<select class='form-control addInput add_fuel_type' id='select_fuel_type' name='add_fuel_type'>"+ optionsFuelType+"</select>  <small class='text-danger' id='err-fuel_type'></small>", 
          "<input class='form-control addInput add_fuel_price' id='add_new_fuel_price' type='number' name='add_fuel_price'> <small class='text-danger' id='err-fuel_price'></small>", 
          "<i class='fa fa-play SaveDataBtn' onclick='validate_Form()' id='saveNewFuelZone' style='cursor: pointer;'></i><i class='fa fa-trash pl-4 cancleBtn' style='cursor: pointer;'></i>"];
    // Add New Inline Row
          table.row.add(row).draw(false);
          table.order([1]).draw();
```

How can I get datepicker In datatables all row and while adding new row?

Comment: You have duplicate IDs, you need to parameterize the name and ID values of all of your elements to include the index of the row (to make them unique). Instead of using the datepicker ID, use a class and apply that class to all of the elements that require a datepicker.

Comment: Hi @mattytommo thanks alot. it works for me for Inline Row Edit.  but its not working for the Inline Row Add when I'm adding new row.

Comment: In the var row, you've put id='date_picker' , so new row being added has this id and datepicker is not being attached to this. I'd suggest putting datepicker on class rather than Id